# Ajax Post Data to controller not working, Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to post the value of checkbox to controller using ajax. But the data which I send, is always empty in controller.

my_view.php

```
<div class="regions">
                         <label class="check-inline">
                             <input type="checkbox" id="sangli" name="region[]" value="Sangli" class="category"
                                    onclick="javascript:updateregion()"
                                    > Sangli</label><br>
                         <label class="check-inline">
                             <input type="checkbox" id="satara" name="region[]" value="Satara" class="category"
                                    onclick="javascript:updateregion()"
                               >Satara</label><br>
                        <label class="check-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="kolhapur" name="region[]" value="Kolhapur" class="category"
                                   onclick="javascript:updateregion()"
                               >Kolhapur</label><br>
                        <label class="check-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="solapur" name="region[]" value="Solapur" class="category"
                                   onclick="javascript:updateregion()"
                                   >Solapur</label><br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="filterbyregion" id="filterbyregion"> 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function updateregion() {
                                $("#sangli").change(function() {
                                        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
                                            var textbox = $(this).val();
                                            document.getElementById("filterbyregion").value = textbox;
                                            //document.filters.submit();
                                            alert(textbox);
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                url: '<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                cache: false,
                                                data: {"filterbyregion": textbox},
                                                dataType: 'text',
                                                success: function() {
                                                    alert(textbox);
                                                    $('#filter_div').load('<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div');
                                                },
                                                error: function(error) {
                                                    console.log(error);
                                                    alert(error);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $("#satara").change(function() {
                                        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
                                            var textbox = $(this).val();
                                            document.getElementById("filterbyregion").value = textbox;
                                            //document.filters.submit();
                                            alert(textbox);
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                url: "<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div",
                                                type: "POST",
                                                cache: false,
                                                data: {"filterbyregion": $("#sangli").val()},
                                                dataType: "text",
                                                success: function() {
                                                    alert(textbox);
                                                    $('#filter_div').load('<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div');
                                                },
                                                error: function(error) {
                                                    console.log(error);
                                                    alert(error);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $("#kolhapur").change(function() {
                                        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
                                            var textbox = $(this).val();
                                            document.getElementById("filterbyregion").value = textbox;
                                            //document.filters.submit();
                                            alert(textbox);
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                url: '<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                cache: false,
                                                data: {"filterbyregion": textbox},
                                                dataType: 'text',
                                                success: function() {
                                                    alert(textbox);
                                                    $('#filter_div').load('<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div');
                                                },
                                                error: function(error) {
                                                    console.log(error);
                                                    alert(error);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $("#solapur").change(function() {
                                        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
                                            var textbox = $(this).val();
                                            document.getElementById("filterbyregion").value = textbox;
                                            //document.filters.submit();
                                            alert(textbox);
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                url: '<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                cache: false,
                                                data: {"filterbyregion": textbox},
                                                dataType: 'text',
                                                success: function() {
                                                    alert(textbox);
                                                    $('#filter_div').load('<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div');
                                                },
                                                error: function(error) {
                                                    console.log(error);
                                                    alert(error);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
</script>
</div>
```

My_controller.php

```
public function view_div() {
        $rgn = str_replace(",", "','", $this->input->post('filterbyregion'));
        $rank = str_replace(",", "','", $this->input->post('ranking'));
        $exp = str_replace(",", "','", $this->input->post('selexperiance'));
        $qual = str_replace(",", "','", $this->input->post('qualification'));
        $sk = str_replace(",","','", $this->input->post('multiskills'));
        if($rgn != ""){
        $this->q['h'] = $this->resource_model->search_users($sk,$rgn,$qual,$exp,$rank);
        $this->q['state'] = $this->place_model->get_state();
        $this->q['district'] = $this->place_model->get_district();
        $this->q['taluka'] = $this->place_model->get_taluka();
        $this->q['courses'] = $this->course_model->get_all_course_names();
            if(isset($this->q['h']) && $this->q['h']->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                    $this->load->view('/web/filtered_resources', $this->q);
            }
        }
        return array();
    }
```

My div is getting loaded but it is without expected result data.

Below is another script which I tried earlier. This may clarify my purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $.noConflict(document).ready(function() {
                            var textbox = "";
                            var rgns = [];
                         if(document.getElementById('sangli').checked) {
                             if (textbox == "") {
                                 textbox += "Sangli";
                             } else {
                                 textbox += ", Sangli";
                             }
                             rgns.push('sangli');
                            }
                            if(document.getElementById('satara').checked) {
                              if (textbox == "") {
                                 textbox += "Satara";
                             } else {
                                 textbox += ", Satara";
                             }
                             rgns.push('satara');
                            }
                            if(document.getElementById('kolhapur').checked) {
                              if (textbox == "") {
                                 textbox += "Kolhapur";
                             } else {
                                 textbox += ", Kolhapur";
                             }
                             rgns.push('satara');
                            }
                            if(document.getElementById('solapur').checked) {
                              if (textbox == "") {
                                 textbox += "Solapur";
                             } else {
                                 textbox += ", Solapur";
                             }
                             rgns.push('satara');
                            }
                            document.getElementById('filterbyregion').value = textbox;
                          //  document.filters.submit();
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: '<?php echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div',
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {"txt": textbox},
                                success: function() {
                            $('#filter_div').load('<?php echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div');
                              },
                                error: function(error) {
                                    console.log(error);
                                }
                             });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass multiple checked checkbox value to the contoller?

Comment: Yes, I am assigning that value to textbox field and then passing it to controller.

Comment: Is there any special purpose of assigning it to a hidden field?

Comment: Not actually...! I tried to send the variable textbox directly instead of assigning it to a hidden field, but unfortunately that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully figure out what you're trying to do. It looks like with this stuff:
    $("#sangli").change(function() {
    });

you are trying to assign the event listener, but you put it inside a function called updateregion() which gets called when you click the checkbox.

I think you need to move the .change() functions outside of your updateregion function. I really can't tell what you're trying to do there though.

My web console was telling me that the updateregion() function wasn't defined, so maybe you want to put that js in the beginning of your file, put it all inside this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //assign event listeners here
});
```

this will ensure that nothing happens until the document is fully loaded. Otherwise part of your javascript might execute before the full page is loaded.

Use firefox and under tools->Web developer->web console you will get more info. Also, check your php error logs, usually in /var/log/apache2/error.log.    In linux you can use the "tail -f error.log" command to see the last 20 lines or so.

I also wouldn't be surprised if something was being lost here:
    $this->input->post('filterbyregion')

Why not just $_POST['filterbyregion']?

If you didn't try to do many different actions in one line, but rather just one action, it would be alot easier for your to dissect where the error is actually occuring.

Comment: I want to filter my results based on the checkbox selected. The checkbox 'sangli will filter my data for Sangli region and so on.   I already tried using $document.ready(function(){                                                                            //my code                                                                                                               } But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<div class="regions">
<label class="check-inline">
 <input type="checkbox" id="sangli" name="region[]" value="Sangli" class="category"
> Sangli</label><br>
<label class="check-inline">
 <input type="checkbox" id="satara" name="region[]" value="Satara" class="category"

   >Satara</label><br>
<label class="check-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="kolhapur" name="region[]" value="Kolhapur" class="category"

   >Kolhapur</label><br>
<label class="check-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="solapur" name="region[]" value="Solapur" class="category"

       >Solapur</label><br>
<input type="hidden" name="filterbyregion" id="filterbyregion"> 

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".category").change(function() {

                var textbox = $(this).val();
                //document.getElementById("filterbyregion").value = textbox;
                $('#filterbyregion').val(textbox);

                /*Fetching multi value from checkbox*/
                var data1 = [];
                $(":checked").each(function() {
                  data1.push($(this).val());
                });
                console.log(data1);
                //document.filters.submit();
                //alert(data1);
               $.ajax({
                    url: 'resource_controller/view_div',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {"filterbyregion": data1},
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        /*$('#filter_div').load('<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div');*/
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });

        });
    </script>
```

On controller:

```
public function view_div() {
    /*Array of checked checkbox value*/
     $rgn = $this->input->post('filterbyregion');
     print_r($rgn);

}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed,    thanks for your quick response! I tried the given code but it doesn't work, neither giving any error nor displaying anything.

Comment: Are you sure ajax request is firing to controller?

Comment: Ajax request is not firing controller for your given code.

Comment: Are you not getting checkbox data in alert , before sending it to ajax controller ? The same code working for me

Comment: replace url with url: "<?php  echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div",

Comment: Yes you are right! I am not getting the checkbox data in alert. Also I tried same code again by adding <?php echo site_url();?>resource_controller/view_div", that too is not working.

Comment: I was having a problem in other javascript. After solving that issue, now my code is working fine. Thank you all for your help!